# How do I bring color to my dwm status bar?

Tags: dwm

I tried to introduce colors to the status bar with xsetroot, but that did not work (of course).
I then found the status2d patch, but it did not use ansi color escape codes and it slows my statusbar down.
Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this patch?
`colored status text`

https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/statuscolors/

[image]

Comment: I have figured it out, but I forgot to come back here, sorry.

Comment: it's good to hear you solved it.

Comment: it adds multi whitespace that spoils the theme of the status bar